# Is the Sedgewick quicksort Algo, flawed

Tags: quicksort

I would say that the optimal Sedgewick Quicksort 3-way partitioning is basically flawed. Gets the correct answer, but not always partitioned correctly, the 3-way partitioning is flawed, and so prone to more swaps and comparisons than would be optimal.

Try this as data, and see what 3 way partition it produces.

"4 4 4 4 9 9 9 9 4 4 4 4"

Partition output "4 4 4 4 4 4 9 9 4 9 9 4" ???

result should be

"4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 9 9 9 9"

But as the answer is (somehow) finally correct, no-one seems to have noticed.

Do I be I wrong ?

Comment: No sorting algorithm is going to be ideal for every possible input set. With small sample sizes like this one, bubble sort can be as fast as quicksort. It's when you get into large sample sizes that using a better sorting algorithm makes a difference.

Comment: My gripe is mainly is on the word optimal, I accept that it is probably pretty good, (I have though in my implementation, fixed the above mentioned problem, could well be slower because of it but at least is works as documented),

Comment: That partition output is not a valid partition. Perhaps there's an error in the transcription from the book to code? Or perhaps there's a typo in the book. Note also that the term "optimal" is used in a very information-theoretical sense (entropy-optimal).

Comment: You can run a test via this link here:- http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/5vCqyw EDIT: click on RUN

Comment: Raymond Chen:- I get exactly the same results via my interpretation of Sedgewick and other peoples. Not a transcription error.

Comment: By the way, code in above link is someone else's, I added the 'HACK' lines to show the error, I had already found the error in my own implementation of Sedgewick. Here original thread on Quicksort on GeeksForGeeks, without my additions:- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3-way-quicksort/ I'm in that thread as StainlessS. At the bottom you'll have to click  'load comments'.

Comment: Here my fix (such as it is) in Avisynth script (but is actually implemented in C in dll).:- http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1782029#post1782029 The (i == j) part is the fix.